# Apply Function Starting from Specific Elements of Array in R

Tags: arrays, r, function, loops, conditional-statements

### Dataset

In R, I have some data that refer to the approximate velocity of a moving object (`velocity`) in relation to specific cases (`ID`) in which the object was presented.

For example:

```
df<-data.frame(ID = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3), velocity = c(10,11,15,28,33,32,33,38,21,10,3,6,9, 21, 54, 44, 31,15, 29, 7, 38, 29))
```

So that:

```
    > df
   ID velocity
1   1       10
2   1       11
3   1       15
4   1       28
5   2       33
6   2       32
7   2       33
8   2       38
9   2       21
10  2       10
11  2        3
12  2        6
13  2        9
14  2       21
15  2       54
16  2       44
17  2       31
18  2       15
19  2       29
20  2       7
21  3       38
22  3       29
```

### Aim:

Now my aim is two-fold. I would like first to identify the `peak` value for `velocity`for each `ID==2` subset and report which specific row contains this `peak` value. Secondly, I would like to apply a function that starts from this specific row, searches backwards/upwards and forwards/downwards (beginning from adjacent values) for all values that meet specific criteria, and "breaks" as soon as the criteria are not met anymore.

### Problem:

While I might have found a solution for the first point, I cannot properly code a function that loops backwards and forwards as described. I will provide an example of what I have done concerning the first issue and the desired outcome pertaining to the second one with the hope some more expert programmer can help me with this matter.

### 1) Find the Peak

What I have basically done is create another column that identifies corresponding row of the `peak` velocity as `TRUE` and the rest as `FALSE`. For this, I used the package `plyr` in order to subset the data.

Here is an example:

```
library(plyr)


df<- ddply(df, .(ID), transform, peak= ifelse(which.max(velocity) == sequence(rle(ID)$lengths), TRUE,FALSE))

    > df
   ID velocity  peak
1   1       10 FALSE
2   1       11 FALSE
3   1       15 FALSE
4   1       28  TRUE
5   2       33 FALSE
6   2       32 FALSE
7   2       33 FALSE
8   2       38 FALSE
9   2       21 FALSE
10  2       10 FALSE
11  2        3 FALSE
12  2        6 FALSE
13  2        9 FALSE
14  2       21 FALSE
15  2       54  TRUE
16  2       44 FALSE
17  2       31 FALSE
18  2       15 FALSE
19  2       29 FALSE
20  2       7  FALSE
21  3       38 TRUE
22  3       29 FALSE
```

I have implemented this procedure for the sake of clarity. This step can probably be nested in the next one concerning the implementation of the function but I await your comments.

### 2) Cycle Backwards and Forwards from TRUE rows

Now, I would like the function to be applied only to `TRUE` rows that have an `ID==2`. In my original set of data ID's are repeated so I will have to apply this function so several other subsets other than the one provided in the example.

Moreover, starting from the row(s) containing the `TRUE`statement, the function has to cycle backwards (considering the `TRUE`being in row `n`, then `n-1, n-2, n-3, ...` and forwards (considering the `TRUE`being in row `n`, then `n+1, n+2, n+3, ...` and label every other element of a row as `TRUE`if a condition is met. Such condition is that every neighboring value is labelled to `TRUE`if it is higher than `velocity/5` of `peak`both in the backwards and forwards directions. As soon as a value is lower than this value, then the function labels everything as `FALSE` distinctly for each direction (backwards/forwards) for the rest of the subset (`ID`)

Hence, if we consider the above `data.frame` as example, `peak == 54` has been classified as the `peak` value in `velocity` for that specific `ID` range.

```
    > df
   ID velocity  peak
1   1       10 FALSE
2   1       11 FALSE
3   1       15 FALSE
4   1       28  TRUE
5   2       33 FALSE
6   2       32 FALSE
7   2       33 FALSE
8   2       38 FALSE
9   2       21 FALSE
10  2       10 FALSE
11  2        3 FALSE
12  2        6 FALSE
13  2        9 FALSE
14  2       21 FALSE
15  2       54  TRUE***
16  2       44 FALSE
17  2       31 FALSE
18  2       15 FALSE
19  2       29 FALSE
20  2       7  FALSE
21  3       38 TRUE
22  3       29 FALSE
```

Then the function checks whether the `velocty`value in the preceding row (`n-1`) is higher than `54/5=10.8`. In this case it is true 21>10.8. The row is then labelled as `TRUE` and the function continues to loop backwards. In the second case (row 13), 9<10.8. As a result the function labels this row as false as it does not meet the specified criteria and every other backward row for the current subset`ID==2`is labelled as `FALSE`.

```
    ID velocity  peak
1   1       10 FALSE
2   1       11 FALSE
3   1       15 FALSE
4   1       28  TRUE
5   2       33 FALSE
6   2       32 FALSE
7   2       33 FALSE
8   2       38 FALSE
9   2       21 FALSE
10  2       10 FALSE
11  2        3 FALSE
12  2        6 FALSE
13  2        9 FALSE
14  2       21 TRUE**
15  2       54  TRUE***
16  2       44 FALSE
17  2       31 FALSE
18  2       15 FALSE
19  2       29 FALSE
20  2       7  FALSE
21  3       38 TRUE
22  3       29 FALSE
```

In the forward direction however, the values in `velocity` in rows, 16:19 are all >10.8. Thus, these rows are labelled as `TRUE`contrarily to row 20 that has a value of 7. From this point onward every other row in the same subset `ID==2`is labelled as `FALSE`.

```
    ID velocity  peak
1   1       10 FALSE
2   1       11 FALSE
3   1       15 FALSE
4   1       28  TRUE
5   2       33 FALSE
6   2       32 FALSE
7   2       33 FALSE
8   2       38 FALSE
9   2       21 FALSE
10  2       10 FALSE
11  2        3 FALSE
12  2        6 FALSE
13  2        9 FALSE
14  2       21 TRUE**
15  2       54  TRUE***
16  2       44 TRUE**
17  2       31 TRUE**
18  2       15 TRUE**
19  2       29 TRUE**
20  2       7  FALSE
21  3       38 TRUE
22  3       29 FALSE
```

The latest data.frame included resembles an example of the desired output. I hope I explained my problem in the correct way and looking forward to your comments.

Answer (score 1):

You can definitely write this with `for` loops, although it will be terribly slow with large datasets (i.e. >100,000 observations). If you need efficiency, implementing this part in Rcpp could be a solution.

Anyway, this seems to produce the desired output:

```
df_out = NULL
for(i in unique(df$ID)){
    # subset
    df_temp = df[df$ID==i,]
    df_temp$peak = FALSE

    # find peak
    max_velocity = max(df_temp$velocity)
    peak_pos = which(df_temp$velocity == max_velocity)

    # search backward
    for(r in peak_pos:1){
            if(df_temp$velocity[r] > max_velocity/5) df_temp$peak[r] = TRUE
            else break
    }

    # search forward
    for(r in (peak_pos):nrow(df_temp)){
            if(df_temp$velocity[r] > max_velocity/5) df_temp$peak[r] = TRUE
            else break
    }

    df_out = rbind(df_out, df_temp)
}
df_out
```

Comment: Appreciate the answer. It would be nice however to have also different approaches since, as you said, this could be quite time-consuming for large datasets.